# Find Out If Two HANDLEs are Hardlinks to the Same File

Tags: winapi, handle, ntfs, hardlink

(This question is a toughie... it might require knowledge of NTFS and/or the use of NT Native APIs; be warned.) :)

If I'm given two `HANDLE`s to two files, how can I *definitively* (not just with high probability) find out if the two `HANDLE`s belong to the exact same file and stream on the disk?

This means, for example, checking the 8-byte NTFS file IDs isn't enough, because two `HANDLE`s with the same file ID can be pointing to different data streams of the same file, and I need to find out if the two streams are really the same and only differ by the name (hardlink).

(What's the use? This way, if I want to perform an operation on all files inside a folder, I don't do the operation twice on the same data stream with different names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953%28VS.85%29.aspx)(), asking for FileStreamInfo.  That returns the stream name.

This warning in the SDK docs should be noted:

> Certain file information classes
>   behave slightly differently on
>   different operating system releases.
>   These classes are supported by the
>   underlying drivers, and any
>   information they return is subject to
>   change between operating system
>   releases.

Avoid relying on recovering info that is (or should be) readily available in your program.

Comment: It's also worth noting that GetFileInformationByHandleEx is only available on Vista and above. (XP cannot die soon enough, IMO. :))

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that XP compatibility is important. :( But I guess this is better than nothing -- *if* combined with `NtQueryObject`, so that I can compare both the path and the stream name. Thanks! (Come to think of it, `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FILE_STREAM_INFORMATION` would probably work on XP...)

Comment: @Leo @Lambert For XP you can get this function by linking against FileExtd.lib, at least according to the MSDN doc, so it looks like it is an option on XP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I just realized, this doesn't seem to do exactly what I want... `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` returns a *list* of streams for the current file, *not* the *current* stream. It doesn't tell me if the two handles are the same underlying stream. Am I missing anything?