# Testing equivalence of file paths

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems

There are two strings in a program. Each of them contains a path to some file or folder. How can I check in C++ whether these paths are to the same file/folder? Can I use the Windows API to do this?

Comment: `wcscmp` not good enough for you ?

Comment: @SS 'Kain': Think about relative filenames. For example "..\..\date\file.dat" could mean the same as "..\file.dat"

Comment: @SS: Perhaps the fact that `wcscmp` does not do what the OP has indicated that he's trying to do, might be a bit of a blocker there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637486/find-out-if-two-handles-are-hardlinks-to-the-same-file *may* help here.

Comment: He didn't specify that those could be relative paths, so I acted instinctively, sorry for that, anyways '_wcsicmp' would do a much better job than my originally proposed function :)

Comment: @SS: Look at sehe's comment on Daniel's answer. There is so much more to consider than relative paths. String comparison is simply _not_ sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You might use [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

*It has the added weight of being cross-platform; this is obviously also a potential advantage. Note the bolded API reference below in case you want to check it out: GetFileInformationByHandle*.

### [equivalent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#equivalent)

```
bool equivalent(const path& p1, const path& p2);
bool equivalent(const path& p1, const path& p2, system::error_code& ec);
```

**Effects**: Determines file_status s1 and s2, as if by status(p1) and  status(p2), respectively.

> **Returns**: true, if sf1 == sf2 and p1 and p2 resolve to the same file system entity, else false.
>
> Two paths are considered to resolve to the same file system entity if two candidate entities reside on the same device at the same location. This is determined as if by the values of the POSIX  stat structure, obtained as if by  stat() for the two paths, having equal st_dev values and equal st_ino values.
>
> [**Note**: POSIX requires that "st_dev must be unique within a Local Area Network". Conservative POSIX implementations may also wish to check for equal st_size and st_mtime values. Windows implementations may use  **GetFileInformationByHandle**() as a surrogate for stat(), and consider "same" to be equal values for dwVolumeSerialNumber, nFileIndexHigh, nFileIndexLow, nFileSizeHigh, nFileSizeLow, ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime, and ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime. -- end note]
>
> **Throws**: filesystem_error if (!exists(s1) && !exists(s2)) || (is_other(s1) && is_other(s2)), otherwise as specified in  Error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Check out GetFullPathName: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Or `PathCanonicalize` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569(VS.85).aspx

Comment: GetFullPathName does not convert the specified file name, only the path.  So you still have to deal with the filename which could not only have case differences, but could be a short name (thisismyfile.txt and THISIS~1.TXT)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, outPath, outSize, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | VOLUME_NAME_GUID)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the path strings to PIDLs using `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`, `SHParseDisplayName()`, or `ILCreateFromPath()`, then compare the PIDLs to each other using `IShellFolder::CompareIDs()` or `ILIsEqual()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)'s answer I came up with this:
It handles many cases like environmental variables, network drives and subst mapping (even when it maps to \\ServerName\Folder), but I'm sure there are cases that I have not thought of.

```
typedef std::wstring String;
void FixPath(const String& aPath, wchar_t* pBuff, DWORD nBuffSize)
{
    wchar_t* canoPath = nullptr;
    bool hasBeenSet = false;

    ::ZeroMemory(pBuff, sizeof(wchar_t) * nBuffSize);
    ::ExpandEnvironmentStrings(aPath.c_str(), pBuff, nBuffSize);
    ::PathAllocCanonicalize(pBuff, PATHCCH_ALLOW_LONG_PATHS, &canoPath);
    ::ZeroMemory(pBuff, sizeof(wchar_t) * nBuffSize);
    if ((2 < wcslen(canoPath)) && (L':' == canoPath[1]))
    {
        wchar_t devName[] = { canoPath[0], L':', L'\0' };
        wchar_t targetPath[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD len = ARRAYSIZE(targetPath);
        wchar_t* p = nullptr;

        ::ZeroMemory(targetPath, sizeof(targetPath));
        if (NO_ERROR == ::WNetGetConnection(devName, targetPath, &len))
            p = targetPath;
        else
        {
            len = ::QueryDosDevice(devName, targetPath, ARRAYSIZE(targetPath)); // Check for subst mapping
            if ((6 < len) && (0 == _wcsnicmp(targetPath, L"\\??\\", 4)))
            {
                p = &targetPath[4];
                if (0 == _wcsnicmp(p, L"UNC", 3)) // if subst was used to directly map to \\serverName\folder
                {
                    p = p + 2;
                    *p = L'\\';
                }
            }
        }
        if(nullptr != p)
        {
            wchar_t* s = &canoPath[2];

            if (L'\\' == *s)
                s++;
            if (L'\0' == *s) // if the passed in path was just the drive letter (Dos Device) and that letter was a subst to another location, there will be nothing is s to append
                ::StringCchCopy(pBuff, nBuffSize, p);
            else
            {
                ::PathCchCombine(pBuff, nBuffSize, p, s);
                ::GetLongPathName(pBuff, pBuff, nBuffSize);
            }
            hasBeenSet = true;
        }
    }
    if (!hasBeenSet)
        ::GetLongPathName(canoPath, pBuff, nBuffSize);
    ::LocalFree(canoPath);
}

#define ILFreeEx(pIdl)\
    if(nullptr != pIdl)\
    {\
        ::ILFree(pIdl);\
        pIdl = nullptr;\
    }

bool SamePath(const String& pathA, const String& pathB)
{
    wchar_t fullPathA[2048];
    wchar_t fullPathB[2048];
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdlA = nullptr;
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdlB = nullptr;
    bool retVal = false;
    
    FixPath(pathA, fullPathA, ARRAYSIZE(fullPathA));
    FixPath(pathB, fullPathB, ARRAYSIZE(fullPathB));
    pIdlA = ::ILCreateFromPath(fullPathA);
    pIdlB = ::ILCreateFromPath(fullPathB);
    if ((nullptr != pIdlA) && (nullptr != pIdlB))
        retVal = ::ILIsEqual(pIdlA, pIdlB);
    else
        retVal = (0 == _wcsicmp(fullPathA, fullPathB));
    ILFreeEx(pIdlA);
    ILFreeEx(pIdlB);
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use **substr** of the String library. 
First, you have to put #include  for call substr correctly.
Look at this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Good luck

Comment: String munging != file system logic (hardlinks, symlinks, UNC paths, mapped drive letters, case insensitivity...)

Comment: And cplusplus.com is a horrendous resource. Let's not recommend its use.

Comment: @Tomalak: what do you use (except bookshelves)?

Comment: Oh, I forget relative paths, embedded `..\..\` and special devices. Maybe more

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Could you give an explanation why or is it just your opinion?

Comment: @Nobody: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Thanks for that. Maybe we should spread the link  more so cplusplus.com vanishs from the first search hits at google ;) That was the main reason for me using it and as I did not know about its flaws I did not consider using another source.

Comment: @Nobody: Unfortunately you are not alone. One day I shall steal that domain name!